# Windows Batch Sort Function doesn't produce output as expected

Tags: windows, powershell, sorting, batch-file

I have been trying to sort the text file using Windows batch Sort function. But the results are not as expected. The input file is something like this:

name2.txt

```
77 
76 
75 
74 
73 
72 
78 
69 
68 
67 
66 
65 
64 
63 
71 
62
9
8
7
```

and the output that I get is as below:

sorted.txt

```
9 
8 
78 
77 
76 
75 
74 
73 
72 
71 
70 
7 
69 
68 
67 
66 
65 
64 
63
```

The code snippet is:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "names="
for /L %%i in (1,1,9) do set "names=!names! C:\offsite_tlog\%%i*.tlg" 
dir /B /A-D /O-D %names% > name1.txt
for /F "tokens=1 delims==." %%a in (name1.txt) do echo %%a >> name2.txt
powershell.exe -command " & {Get-Content "C:\offsite\name2.txt" | Sort-Object -Descending > sorted.txt}"
```

The normal Windows batch sort is also not working. So, kindly assist me with sorting

The expected output should be

```
7
8
9
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
```

Comment: On DosTips.com they have a helper batch file that sorts numerically. http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeBatchFiles.php#_Toc145951142

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, but when you use `Get-Content`, it's treating the file as a string, not a number.

```
[Array]$Output = @()
Get-Content -LiteralPath "C:\offsite\name2.txt" |
  ForEach-Object { $Output += [Int]($_.Trim()) }

$Output | Sort-Object | Out-File -Path .\sorted.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much...it is working....but I made small change to the above code as it was throwing me error
[Array]$Output = @()
Get-Content -LiteralPath "C:\offsite\name2.txt" |
  ForEach-Object { $Output += [Int]($_.Trim()) }
$Output | Sort-Object | Out-File C:\offsite\sorted.txt

Comment: Forcing the interpretation of the input lines as integers is indeed the crucial pointer, but duplicating the input lines in an integer array built up in a `ForEach-Object` loop is both unnecessary and inefficient (both in terms of memory use and performance). On a minor note: `.Trim()` is not necessary to cast a string to an `[int]`.

Answer (score 0):

This wrapped PowerShell script will leftpad all numbers with zeroes to 10 places and sort on that virtual key.

```
powershell -NoP -C "gc 'C:\offsite\name2.txt'|Sort -desc {[Regex]::Replace($_,'\d+',{$args[0].Value.PadLeft(10,'0')})}|sc sorted.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest PowerShell solution is:

```
Get-Content 'C:\offsite\name2.txt' | Sort-Object { [int] $_ } > sorted.txt
```

Script block `{ [int] $_ }` converts each input line (`$_`) to an integer for the purpose of sorting.

Note that `>` creates a "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) file; use `Out-File` or `Set-Content` with `-Encoding` to change the character encoding.

Invoked from `cmd.exe`:

```
powershell -c "Get-Content 'C:\offsite\name2.txt' | Sort-Object { [int] $_ } >sorted.txt"
```